# (Linux) Read mutliple files as a single one without having to copy the chunks to a new file first

Tags: linux, io, named-pipes, fuse

(Linux) The problem at hand is the following:

Let's suppose we have **foo_1** and **foo_2** being in fact 2 chunks of the **foo** file, such as the command:

```
cat foo_1 foo_2 >foo
```

I would like a system to be able to consider {foo_1 + foo_2} as a single foo file **without having to copy it first** with the command above.

Depending on the command you use to read {foo_1 + foo_2], say you want a md5sum, you can just use named pipes, and it provides the feature.

You would do:

```
mkfifo my_named_pipe
cat foo_1 foo_2 >my_named_pipe &
md5sum my_named_pipe
```

That works!

But named pipes have a **big limitation: all accesses must be sequential** (no seek), since it is basically a pipe.

Hence this "named pipes" method is not a "generic read multiple files as a virtual single file".

Indeed that works in the example below for md5sum, because md5sum need only sequential reading of the file.
Now if that file was say a rar file or a video you would like to read with VLC, or an ISO you would like to mount and do random access on, that will fail since those softwares need not-sequential reads.

**Question:**
so, before calling the calvary, I mean writing myself a fuse filesystem that will do what I described above to save precious I/O and space, I would like to know if you have heard of a generic method to do so.

What I am thinking of is something looking like:

```
fuseVirtualFile mountpoint foo foo_1 foo_2
```

That would show the "virtual file" foo under mountpoint, so mountpoint/foo

This "virtual file" would be the read-only concatenation of foo_1 and foo_2, without having to actually do the write I/O which saves time, disk space, and wear on the SSD!

Comment: Padding issues aside, maybe one could mmap() the two files into adjacant memory space?

Comment: Thanks, and I'll look into that if I have to build a fuse filesystem myself, as my web research didn't return any doing so. My research for now is not at the programming level, but rather a mechanism (like named pipes) that can be used with any generic shell or interactive programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since it apparently didn't exist, I just create it!

Behold: **mfs**

This is a fuse filesystem that will do as asked by my question, which is "virtually merge several files into a single one".

Then it becomes possible to access (read-only) the merged file as if it had actually been merged into a single file by a `cat` command.

As already stated in the question, this is only useful if you need random read acces, since stream access can be done via named pipes.

Here it is: https://github.com/Bylon/mfs

Enjoy!